# I would like to add multiple forms on this code

Tags: javascript, html, css, deployment

I have this code, made it through a tutorial i found online and edited most of it myself, mostly regarding to the buttons that show the info, but i'm not really sure how to add different forms on each section, im pretty much still learning.

i would massively appreciate the help, the idea is that each section has it's own form and can work separetly, also add more sections, but if i can make at least two forms that works on their own without any error i can replicate that easily, i just need to know how to get there, but that's the overall idea

heres my code

````
    /*======COMIENZO DEL FORMULARIO======*
    *{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
    }
    
    body{
        min-height: 100vh;
        background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #3498db, #8e44ad);
    }
    
    .formulario{
        width: 360px;
        background: #f1f1f1;
        height: 400px;
        padding: 80px 40px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }
    
    .formulario h1{
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 60px;
        color: #333;
        font-weight: 600;
    }
    
    .box-input{
        border-bottom: 2px solid #adadad;
        position: relative;
        margin: 30px 0;
    }
    
    .box-input input{
        font-size: 16px;
        color: #333;
        border: none;
        width: 100%;
        outline: none;
        background: none;
        padding: 0 5px;
        height: 40px;
    }
    
    .box-input span::before {
        content: attr(data-placeholder);
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 5px;
        color: #adadad;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        z-index: -1;
        transition: .5s;
    }

    .box-input label {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 5px;
        color: #adadad;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        z-index: -1;
        transition: .5s;
    }
    
    .box-input span::after{
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        width: 0%;
        height: 2px;
        background: linear-gradient(120deg, #3498db, #8e44ad);
        transition: .5s;
    }
    
    .focus + span::before{
        top: -5px;
    }
    
    .focus + span::after{
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    .boton{
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: #48bb78;
        border: solid 2px #48bb78;
        color: #fff;
        border-radius: 5px;
        font-weight: 600;
        font-size: 18px;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }
    
    .boton:hover{
        background-color: #2F855A;
        border: solid 2px #2F855A;
        transition: .5s;
    }*======FIN DEL FORMULARIO======*/

    #hide-logo, #hide-mascota, #hide-web {
        display: none;
    }
    
    .hide-content {
        display: none;
    }

    .styled-button {
        background-color: red;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <div>
        <div><!--LOGOS-->
            <button id="show-logo" value="Click to show" onclick="showContent('logo')">Click to show</button>
            
            <button id="hide-logo" class="styled-button" value="Click to hide" onclick="hideContent('logo')">Click to hide</button>
            
            <!--<div id="logo" class="hide-content">Text to be shown and hidden 1</div>-->

            <div id="logo" class="hide-content">
                <form id="formulario" class="formulario">
                    <h1>Envío de formulario por WhatsApp</h1>
                    <div class="box-input">
                        <input name="nombre" id="nombre" type="text" required>
                        <span data-placeholder="Escriba su Nombre"></span>
                    </div>
            
                    <div class="box-input">
                        <input name="apellidos" id="apellidos" type="text" required>
                        <span data-placeholder="Escriba sus Apellidos"></span>
                    </div>
            
                    <div class="box-input">
                        <input name="email" id="email" type="email" required>
                        <span data-placeholder="Escriba su Correo Electrónico"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="box-input">
                        <label for="logo">LOGO</label><input name="logo" id="logo" type="radio" value="LOGO" required>
                    </div>
                    
                    <!--<button onclick="getValues()">Get Values</button>
                    <p>TOTAL:</p>
                    <div id="total">$</div>-->
            
                    <button id="submit-logo" type="submit" class="boton-logo"><i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i>Enviar WhatsApp</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div><!--MASCOTAS-->
            <button id="show-mascota" value="Click to show" onclick="showContent('mascota')">Click to show</button>
            
            <button id="hide-mascota" class="styled-button" value="Click to hide" onclick="hideContent('mascota')">Click to hide</button>
            
            <div id="mascota" class="hide-content">Text to be shown and hidden 2</div>
        </div>

        <div><!--WEB-->
            <button id="show-web" value="Click to show" onclick="showContent('web')">Click to show</button>
            
            <button id="hide-web" class="styled-button" value="Click to hide" onclick="hideContent('web')">Click to hide</button>
            
            <div id="web" class="hide-content">Text for new content</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".box-input input").on("focus", function(){
            $(this).addClass("focus");
        });
        
        $(".box-input input").on("blur", function(){
            if($(this).val() == ""){
                $(this).removeClass("focus");
            }
        });
    </script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
    <script>
        //COMIENZO DE CALCULO
        //function getValues() {
            //let formulario = document.getElementById('formulario');
            //let formData = new FormData(formulario);

            //let total = 0;

            //for (var value of formData.values()) {
                //total += parseInt(value);
            //}

            //document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total;

            //console.log(total);
        //}//FIN CALCULO

        //COMIENZO DEL FORMILARIO
        function isMobile() {
            if (sessionStorage.desktop)
                return false;
            else if (localStorage.mobile)
                return true;
            var mobile = ['iphone', 'ipad', 'android', 'blackberry', 'nokia', 'opera mini', 'windows mobile', 'windows phone', 'iemobile'];
            for (var i in mobile)
                if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf(mobile[i].toLowerCase()) > 0) return true;
            return false;
        }
        
        const formulario = document.querySelector('#formulario');
        const buttonSubmit = document.querySelector('#submit');
        const urlDesktop = 'https://web.whatsapp.com/';
        const urlMobile = 'whatsapp://';
        const telefono = '584129526003';
        
        formulario.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
            event.preventDefault()
            buttonSubmit.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-circle-notch fa-spin"></i>'
            buttonSubmit.disabled = true
            setTimeout(() => {
                let nombre = document.querySelector('#nombre').value
                let apellidos = document.querySelector('#apellidos').value
                let email = document.querySelector('#email').value

                let logoElement = document.querySelector('input[name="logo"]:checked');
                let logo = "";
                if (logoElement) {
                    logo = logoElement.value;
                }

                let mensaje = 'send?phone=' + telefono + '&text=*_SERVICIOS A CONTRATAR_*%0A*¿Cual es tu nombre?*%0A' + nombre + '%0A*¿Cuáles son tus apellidos?*%0A' + apellidos + '%0A*¿Cuál es tu correo electrónico?*%0A' + email + '%0A*Servicio que necesito*%0A' + logo + ''
                if(isMobile()) {
                    window.open(urlMobile + mensaje, '_blank')
                } else{
                window.open(urlDesktop + mensaje, '_blank')
                }
                buttonSubmit.innerHTML = '<i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i> Enviar WhatsApp'
                buttonSubmit.disabled = false
            }, 3000);
        });

        // SECCIONES DESPLEGABLES
        // estilo inicial para el primer botón
        document.getElementById('show-logo').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('hide-logo').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('logo').style.display = 'block';

        function showContent(contentId) {
            document.getElementById('show-' + contentId).style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('hide-' + contentId).style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById(contentId).style.display = 'block';
            
            // Ocultar los otros contenidos
            var otherContentId1, otherContentId2;
            if (contentId === 'logo') {
                otherContentId1 = 'mascota';
                otherContentId2 = 'web';
            } else if (contentId === 'mascota') {
                otherContentId1 = 'logo';
                otherContentId2 = 'web';
            } else {
                otherContentId1 = 'logo';
                otherContentId2 = 'mascota';
            }
            document.getElementById('show-' + otherContentId1).style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('hide-' + otherContentId1).style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById(otherContentId1).style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('show-' + otherContentId2).style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('hide-' + otherContentId2).style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById(otherContentId2).style.display = 'none';
        }

        function hideContent(contentId) {
            document.getElementById('show-' + contentId).style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('hide-' + contentId).style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById(contentId).style.display = 'none';
        }
    </script>
</body>```
````

Comment: Almost all of the CSS is commented out. Please only post the code that's relevant to the question, not code that isn't used.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to explain from your sample code, because there's a lot going on there, but here's a place for you to get started.

You could add the same class for all forms, and simply loop through them. (Not same ID because they are unique)

```js
// Get all forms
const forms = document.querySelectorAll('.form')

// Loop through each form
forms.forEach(form => {
  // Get this form submit button
  const submit = form.querySelector('.submit')
  
  // Get this form input
  const input = form.querySelector('input')

  // Add click event for submit
  submit.addEventListener('click', e => {
    // Prevent page reload for demo purposes
    e.preventDefault()
    
    // Log input value
    console.log(input.value)
  })
})
```

```html
<form class="form">
  <input type="text" value="Form 1">
  <button class="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<hr>

<form class="form">
  <input type="text" value="Form 2">
  <button class="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```